# getting value of an element and make it the value of an attribute in XSLT?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt

I am transforming an xml file into a structurally different xml file with xslt.
I want to get the value of an element in the old file and make it the value of an attribute in the new file. However, the code does not work in attributes. This is what I want to see:

From

```
<cell n="1">1285</cell>
```

To

```
<date value="1285">1285<date>
```

In XSLT I wrote this

```
<date when="<xsl:value-of select="t:cell[1]"/>"><xsl:value-of select="t:cell[1]"/></date>
```

But it does not work within the attribute. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="cell">
  <date>
    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </date>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is

```
<date value="1285">1285</date>
```

---

Or, in one (shorter) line basing on the `cell` context element (using an *attribute value template*):

```
<xsl:template match="cell">
  <date value="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></date>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks ! But instead of <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute> one must use <xsl:attribute name="when"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute> !!

Comment: I added a shorter solution to the answer. Maybe that simplifies things.

Comment: million thanks, now I understood the logic!!